# No trap in this one

Tags: knowledge, visual, lateral-thinking

This visual puzzle resolves to a **number**.
[image]

HINT

> The title is stuffed with hints:) The puzzle is actually cluing a relatively well known and culture related thing in an unorthodox but logical (??) way. One of its components provides the opportunity for self-checking.

Hint2

> "?" Means "to ask"

Hint3

> Almost 18

Hint4

> Logically, the propositions are forced to cancel each other, so they form a "nonsense biconditional statement", which means, the conclusion will be nonsense, too. Metaphorically it would make a bit more sense, it means: from certain real world situations, sometimes it is impossible to ...

Hint5

> Sun, conifer and cloud are decorations and they show basic directions, but they have no more meaning in relation to the content.

Hint6

> So, I hinted "ask", and an answerer said "OK", "mad", and he also guessed an "aeroplane" (apparently there is no aeroplane, but this guess is very sensible)...and the things left are signs borrowed from formal logic.

Hint7

> Just let's take a look at a random line. The necessary hints have been given already; So, for example, it looks like: "'Ask' 'implies' 'OK'"

Comment: Time for hint, maybe? :)

Comment: Hmm... Hints..Hard..

Comment: Is it Rot13(bar)?

Comment: Rot13 vf gur nafjre puevfgznff????

Comment: The layout looks like video games

Comment: @Always Confused, it might look like so,but this is not related to video games.

Answer (score 1):

> Asking "Is it okay ("OK", rotated 90 degrees right) to jump from Aeroplane (Arrow-plane)?" 
>
>  else (conditional, branchpoint) (if it is not safe) you will madly (nonsensically) CRASH (Cross) into conifer.

So the ? at ground will be

> Cross (X) . The festival is X-mass

and the number is

> XV (15) if we see it together with Caret, together upside down

Comment: Uhh...Incorrect :)